# AngularJS - unchecking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I'm using angularjs as much as possible - I'm editing some legacy system and I cannot afford to change too much. So, basically, I need to implement a function that unchecks every checkbox in the page. The easiest solution - without changing too much of the existing system - was to use `angular.element`. Now I know, this is a REALLY bad solution, but I need to make it work.

Currently, it works (visually at least), since every checkbox gets unchecked, however, on another click the checkbox doesn't work - it needs to be pressed twice, before being activated again.

Here's a demo of how things are and how I've implemented a partial solution: http://jsbin.com/xicubegira/1/edit?html,js,output
Use case is as follows.

- Click on checkbox - the counter will increment to 1, checkbox will become checked
- Click on checkbox again - the counter will increment to 2, checkbox will become unchecked
- Click on checkbox - the counter will increment to 3, checkbox will become checked
- Press the 'uncheck me' button - the counter will not increment, checkbox will become unchecked (which is OK)
- Click on checkbox again - the checkbox becomes 'checked', but the counter is not incremented!

So, how could I uncheck all checkboxes in the page and still maintain initial functionality? I'm guessing the issue here is, that nothing changes in scope of checkbox, so `ng-change` doesn't get fired.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is that you'r not changing your model so ng-change cannot be called since the data hasn't change.
Can't you do a simple set to false of your model :

```
$scope.uncheck = function(){        
    $scope.confirmed = false;
};
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Didn't even have to use `angular.element`, perfect!